# Cannot compile when using libxml

Tags: c, libxml2

I have a source file that I can run via the terminal using

```
gcc source.c -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -o output
```

but when I `#include` the source file which includes the libxml source files, the compiler complains that the `libxml/xmlmemory.h:` , `libxml/parser.h:`, `libxml/xpath.h` cannot be found : no such file or directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need always to keep the `-I/usr/include/libxml2` in your gcc statement, so that it can find the header files.

Comment: What if this file needs to compiled as part of a much larger system? Should I just copy the needed files into the directory where this source file kept?

Comment: Ahah. I hope you're not including the headers from _your_ header files. That would suck. Make sure you depend on libxml2 only internally (in your compilation units, i.e. .c/.cxx/.cpp files)

Comment: I include in the .c files. but doesnt work. I dont have the libxml files in the same directory as the .c I am compiling

Comment: @Helium3, yes whatever c files that needs to use libxml will have to be compiled with the -I option.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `xml2-config --cflags --libs` to retrieve the compilation flags to add.

```
kjp@vbox:~/Dev/ScratchDir$ xml2-config --cflags --libs
-I/usr/include/libxml2
-lxml2
kjp@vbox:~/Dev/ScratchDir$
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It seems like the source is referencing libxml, not libxml2</strike>
Can you verify that

```
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h
```

is in fact accessible? (try to view it)

You don't compile the headers, the headers just have to be accessible as 'description' of the what the libraries implement

Comment: Is it possible the files cannot be found because they arent in the same folder as the code being compiled? I include like so #include <libxml/xpath.h> . i dont specify /usr/include/libxml2/libxml

Comment: It's what -I/usr/include/libxml2 is for

Comment: So how do I do this without calling I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 when compiling?

Comment: Why would you do that? Make a compile script/makefile if you think it tedious. Using absolute paths is going to make your code unportable to other machines

Comment: The thing is that my code is part of a much larger system. Its an embedded project with multiple parts to the system. So it shouldnt have to be compiled with loads of command line arguments. So I should write a makefile?

Comment: Yup see my other comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544074/cannot-compile-when-using-libxml/5544220#5544220

Comment: @sehe : The link you posted looks to be the same URL as the page you included the comment on. Did you have a different page you wanted us to look at? ;-)

Comment: @shelter: it linked to a different answer with my other comment, ty

Comment: @sehe: I replied to your other comment. Im still not sure what to do. Because if the code will be compiled on a pandaboard, the libxml will need to be there anyway, and might have another path. Although the pandaboard will be running ubuntu.